# How can I use a printer with duplex printing to flip pages horizontally?

Tags: print-design

An office printer  had an option for automatic duplex printing, but not manual.  So I had to command it to print firstly all even pages in normal order, and they ended at the paper output tray face-down (p. 2 was at the bottom).

Then I turned them upside down, and placed  them back into the paper feeder tray, so that p. 2 now faced up and was the topmost sheet. I printed all odd pages in normal order. At the paper output tray, the most bottom sheet contains p. 2 (facing down), p. 1 (facing up; reverse of p. 2). The second most bottom sheet contains p. 4 (facing down), p. 3 (facing up; reverse of p. 4). So the front-to-back order is wrong, as it's p. 2, p. 1, p. 4, p. 3.

How can I manipulate this printer to flip pages horizontally, rather than wasting my time flipping manually? Yes, I was foolish not to research first and read [this](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/HowToDoTwoSidedPrinting/index.html).

Comment: Most duplex printers have an option for long edge or short edge... whatever it's set to.. use the other one.

Comment: @Scott Please elaborate?

Comment: I can't. I don't know your printer or it's driver. Most duplex printers have a setting "Long Edge" or "Short Edge"